# Dynamically generated sub-menu items appearing in the top left corner of the screen in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am trying to use an `ItemTemplate` to create a list of menu items based on an enum. The problem is that, when I use the item template, the sub-menu appears in the top left corner of the screen (see Image 1) instead of next to the sub-menu header like the one with items defined within XAML (see image 2).

Items generated from enum:

[image]

Items defined in the XAML:

[image]

I would like to have the items sourced from the resource but still appear inside the menu flow like it does in the second example.

Here is the relevant code:

```xml
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header=" Advanced Filters">
        <MenuItem Header="Status"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Statuses}}">
            <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Converter={StaticResource EnumCaseConverter}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Submenu 2">
            <MenuItem Header="Item 1" />
            <MenuItem Header="Item 2" />
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

If it is relevant, my project includes [Material Design](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit).

[Material design menus example](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MainDemo.Wpf/MenusAndToolBars.xaml)

Comment: maybe you need to wrap it inside a `PopUp` and then setting it's relative position. check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/popup-overview

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to do it programmatically instead of in XAML.

If anyone has a simple fix that is entirely in XAML, I'd be happy to see what the solution is.

```cs
private void PopulateFilterMenu()
{
    // Create sub-menus
    MenuItem status = AddMenuItem(FilterMenu, "Status", false);
    MenuItem type = AddMenuItem(FilterMenu, "Type", false);

    // Add status items
    foreach (string item in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Statuses)))
        AddMenuItem(status, item, true);

    // Add type items
    foreach (string item in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Type)))
        AddMenuItem(type, item, true);
}

private MenuItem AddMenuItem(MenuItem parent, string header, bool checkable = false)
{
    if (parent == null) { return parent; }
    MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem
    {
        Header = EnumCaseConverter.Convert(header),
        IsCheckable = checkable,
        IsChecked = checkable
    };
    parent.Items.Add(menuItem);
    return menuItem;
}
```